# Why do I get this error while calling predict in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm a newbie to Tensorflow, I've done many models but today when calling predict I get this error : ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" (type Sequential).

```
Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,).
```

What is the problem here ?

Thank you !

Comment: Because the input data to your model does not have the correct shape, I guess you have missed the batch dimension. Try add it by `data = np.expand_dims(data,axis=0)`.

Comment: @Kaveh You mean the data for the predict model ? Or even the train and test data ?

Comment: If you have trained your model successfully, you have had the batch in your train data. And if you get an error while predicting, it may be due to missing batch dimension for the data you have passed to the `predict()` function.

Comment: Please share some reproducible code to understand and replicate the error.